# Is GeneratedBy.Increment() thread-safe within a single SessionFactory?

Tags: .net, database, multithreading, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

My application uses

`Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Increment();`

for generating primary keys. I have read a few articles about `Increment` and I am quite worried now: all those articles say `Increment` is dangerous when used in *cluster*. However, have no cluster, it is a common web application with a single `SessionFactory` instance. There are concurrent threads, though, all sharing the same `SessionFactory`.

Should I be worried? What object provides new created instances with their primary key values? Is it the thread-safe `SessionFactory`, or the not-safe `Session`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate/Id/IncrementGenerator.cs), the `Generate()` method of the `IncrementGenerator` class is decorated with the `MethodImpl` attribute and the `MethodImplOptions.Synchronized` option. This [suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx) that access to the method is synchronised and, therefore, thread-safe.